# Optional stopping theorem question

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

> > $X_n$ is an irreducible and aperiodic Markov chain with transition matrix $P$. There is a function $f$ s.t. $Pf(x)\leq\alpha f(x)$ for $x\notin B$, $B$ a finite set and $\alpha<1$. $f(x)>M$ on $x\notin B$. Show 
> >     $$E_x(\tau_B)<\infty$$

I can show that $Y_n:= \alpha^{-n}f(X_n)$ is a super-martingale off of $B$ and let $\tau = \tau_B$. So by optional stopping:

$$\begin{align}
f(x)\geq E_x[Y_{n\wedge \tau}]&= E_x[f(X_{\tau\wedge n}\frac{1}{\alpha^{\tau\wedge n}})] \\
\implies f(x) &\geq \liminf_{n\to \infty} E_x[f(X_{\tau\wedge n}\frac{1}{\alpha^{\tau\wedge n}})] \\
&\geq E_x[\liminf_{n\to \infty} f(X_{\tau\wedge n}\frac{1}{\alpha^{\tau\wedge n}})] \text{ By Fatou's lemma} \\
&\geq E_x M(1/\alpha)^\infty.1_{\tau=\infty} + E_x (1/\alpha)^\tau f(X_\tau) .1_{\tau<\infty}
\end{align}
$$

Since $\alpha<1$, I can see that $P(\tau = \infty)= 0$ but not sure how to go from $\infty>f(x)>E_x [(1/\alpha)^\tau f(X_\tau) .1_{\tau<\infty}]$ to saying $E_x(\tau)<\infty$?

Comment: Is $f$ strictly positive? If so, $f$ is bounded below by some $C>0$ on $B$ and then from what you have shown: $E_x[\alpha^{-\tau}] = E_x[\alpha^{-\tau}; \tau<\infty]\le f(x)/C$. And because $0<\alpha<1$, you have $\tau\le  \alpha^{-\tau}$. [In fact, $\tau$ has finite moments of all orders.]